# Fitting Ambiguity in Real World Data ML Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

the issue I have from concept level in terms of fitting the data while solving real world problem.

Problem Statement: Classification of Text Content 
Data Set Having 2 Columns: Text Content & Category of the Content (Like Sport, News etc..)

Accomplished: Used Random Forest Classifier to built a model - followed some pre processing technique - using TfidfVectorizer transformation. As a result everything is completely working fine with respect to train & test data.

Challenges: When real world text content is coming, I need to transform the data again using TfidfVectorizer --- & this will be having completely different transformation than earlier dataset we have used. Which is giving completely different result as expected.

Question: Is there any way we could save this fitting logic that has been implemented at the time of training so that I can use that information to only transform the data for real time data?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you want to use `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` ?

Comment: Apologies! Example: Suppose we have a column like "Salary" --> It would have a salary range starting from 0 to anything. In a very ideal scenario -- if we are scaling it by MinMaxScaler using the dataset we have!  --- in Real world scenario we will have different data set, There how I would use the same scaled fitted data to new data -- As both dataset are different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take an example of `MinMaxScaler` on Salary column, as you mentioned in your comment:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
```

Then we can fit and transform our training set:

```
scaler.fit(train)
train = scaler.transform(train)
```

We can also transform `test` set in the same way, like this:

```
test = scaler.transform(test)
```

> how I would use the same scaled fitted data to new data ?

We can store that `MinMaxScaler` for future use in a pickle file:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(scaler, open('file/path/scaler.pkl','wb'))
```

Whenever new data comes we can load the pickle file and use it to transform new data:

```
scaler = pickle.load(open('file/path/scaler.pkl','rb'))
new_data = scaler.transform(new_data)
```